# contracts missing from ganache-cli after restart

Tags: ganache-cli

I have a ganache-cli running on an ec2 instance but everytime I restart the ganache-cli the contracts go missing. I have specified a db, a id and also the precious mnemonic and it still is the same.

This is the command I use.

```
ganache-cli -h localhost -p 7545 -db C:\Apps\ganacheDb -m "myth like bonus scare over problem client lizard pioneer submit female collect"
-i  1582605308235
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Suggestion: Try to run ganache-cli locally on your machine, then close it, then run it again. If the problem at hand is solved, then your actual problem is in the configuration of the remote EC2 machine. If the problem at hand persists, then your problem is indeed in the configuration of the ganache-cli process.

Comment: Yes I have tried it on my local machine and it still is the same.

Comment: Good, so now you (we) can investigate the problem on a local machine.

Comment: @goodvibration looks like the solution by Xavier is perfect and it was just a simple mistake on my part

Comment: OK, so [here is the full guide](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#command-line), just in case you need to for future reference.

Comment: nothing was just checking out the feature site gave me. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `--db`.

Note the double `-`.

Comment: Such a simple mistake and has been eating my head for almost 2 days. Lol!